# Emacs macos keyboard handling problem

Tags: macos, services, emacs

I'm looking for "unity-win7" like solution, where I can run cmd+num for activating browser, console, editor etc...
I found Activator and Services in osx, however, I can't use cmd+num because many app like chrome and iterm2 use them to activate tabs.
So I set up Launch Services via Activator on chd+shift+num, and it works everywhere, except Emacs)
It looks like Emacs handle keyboard before Services, so, for example, after cmd+shift+1, it expects "Shell command".
What I need is to make this hotkeys (cmd+shift+num) somehow transparent for emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your .emacs

```
(global-set-key “\M-!” nil)
```

and similarly for the rest of the shifted numbers.

(If you don’t have a .emacs, make a text file called that in your home directory.)

This will unbind whatever functions are attached to those key combinations, so they’ll get passed out of Emacs and off to the rest of the system.

However, if there’s any command there that you use, you’ll need to bind it to a different key combination. Even if you activate things with Escape then the key, that’s just an alias for Meta.

You can see what command is bound to a key with C-h k, then you can bind that function to another key in your .emacs

For instance, if I wanted to move query-replace-regexp, which I have on M-%, I might add these lines:

```
(global-set-key “\M-%” nil) 
(global-set-key “\C-%" 'query-replace-regexp)
```

Your other option would be to change what key to use as Meta, but that would probably be a lot more trouble.